# C# + UWP: Convert Windowspath to ms-appdata uri

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, uri

I'm wrting code for a tool which runs on a raspberry pi. That tool should download an HTML-File and open it in a webview.

After the download The file is located in this path:

```
\\192.168.2.79\c$\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\Packages\f2f9d0b2-0e90-4494-bcbf-12da27846733_dd744mn1wdq44\AC\Temp\de-DE\index.html
```

To open it in a webview it has to look like this (example from MS-Page):

```
ms-appdata:///local/intro/welcome.html
```

how do I convert it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `\\192.168.2.79\c$\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\Packages\f2f9d0b2-0e90-4494-bcbf-12da27846733_dd744mn1wdq44\AC\Temp\de-DE\index.html`.
>   how do I convert it correctly?

Currently,there are only three folders could be accessed using `ms-appdata:///` protocol.

LocalState : `ms-appdata:///local/`

TempState : `ms-appdata:///temp/`

RoamingState : `ms-appdata:///roaming/`

You could not convert the path that you have mentioned to ms-appsata uri directly. For your requirement , you could copy the html file to `LocalState` folder and convert the file path like following:

`ms-appdata:///local/tem/index.html`

For more you could refer to [ApplicationData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalCacheFolder) Class.

Comment: thnx .. it works but you have to create another subfolder in local. otherwise you'll get an error.